# Yesod - Maybe EntityId to Maybe Entity

Tags: haskell, yesod

First of all I'm a Haskell noob so if there is something obvious I'm doing wrong sorry.

Say I have something like:

```
Object1
    stuff Text
    other Object2Id Maybe

Object2
    otherStuff Text
```

in my config/models file

How do I get the Object2 associated to Object1 if I have a handler of type:

```
getObject1R :: Object1Id -> Handler Html
```

If I understand correctly I want to go from a `Maybe Object2Id` to a `Maybe Object` with calling `runDB $ get` in the middle and with everything I've tried the types don't line up properly.

Thanks

*EDIT*

here is one attempt that I feel is close but isn't correct:

```
object1 <- runDB $ get object1Id
maybeObj2 <- case (object1Other object1) of
    Just obj2Id -> Just $ runDB $ get obj2Id
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

*EDIT 2 (figured it out)*

So I figured out how to get it to compile and work! Thanks for the comments and help.

here is my code (in the handler):

```
(object1, maybeObject2) <- runDB $ do
    object1 <- get404 object1Id
    maybeObject2 <- case (object1Other object1) of
      Just object2Id -> get object2Id
      Nothing -> return Nothing
    return (object1,maybeObject2)
```

I'm sure there are better/faster/easier ways to do it, but this worked.

Comment: if you have an `obj1Id :: Object1Id` then `maybeObj2Id <- fmap object1Other <$> get obj1Id` should give you a `Maybe Object2Id` (inside a `runDB $ do` block) - as you can see ther are two `fmap`s - one to get into the db-monad and the other for the `Maybe`

Comment: i haven't tried that ... do you not need the runDB?

Comment: inside yesods `Handler`? Yes!

Comment: oops there is another `Maybe`in your `other` so you might want an additional `join` ^^

Comment: ok so that would give you a `Maybe Object2Id` right? ... how do i get the object then? is there a `get` function that support a `Maybe EntityId`?

Comment: it's probably best if you just use `obj1 <- get objectId1` and then do a `case obj1 of ...` and similar to parse through - but `mapM` will do (but I guess it won't get more readable)

Comment: figured it out ... thanks to you comment about using a `runDB $ do` block ... i'll update question with answer, but if you'd like to create an answer @Carsten I'll accept yours.

Comment: I think it's fine - all your work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out how to get it to compile and work! Thanks for the comments and help.

here is my code (in the handler):

```
(object1, maybeObject2) <- runDB $ do
    object1 <- get404 object1Id
    maybeObject2 <- case (object1Other object1) of
      Just object2Id -> get object2Id
      Nothing -> return Nothing
    return (object1,maybeObject2)
```

I'm sure there are better/faster/easier ways to do it, but this worked.